# How CSMA/CA works on XBee?

Tags: collision, xbee

I'm trying to implement S-MAC protocol on waspmote xbee sensors and i know it has its own CSMA/CA. So first of all I need to understand the basic of xBee collision avoidance.
Two senders set up in api mode in libraries and both periodically sending single bytes to a common receiver. I reduce the delay and many changing in libabries to make collision and to see how algorithm works. But when i monitor data at the receiver all looks as expected at the receiver .. byte1, byte 2 .. byte1, byte2. 
Do u have any idea how can i make collision?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sniffing the 802.15.4 traffic?  That's the only way you'd see a collision.

The XBee module buffers the data you want to send, using the host communication parameters (baud rate, API mode, etc.) and then sends it out over 802.15.4 at 250kbps.  The module has all of the collision avoidance built in, and will retransmit as necessary to deliver your message.  If it's unable to deliver after some number of transmission attempts, you'll get a Transmit Status frame indicating failure.

On the receiving end, it buffers the data and delivers it to the local host using local serial settings (baud rate and API mode).

If you're trying to implement S-MAC, you need a different radio processor where you have low-level control over the radio.  The XBee module provides an application layer and handles the MAC layer itself.

Comment: Yes im sniffing the 802.15.4 traffic. Actually this is my final project and i should have done this problem till now but still struggling with it. Its really hard to get it cuz im pretty new at this so i have many questions..
Is it possible to modify xbee module firmware? i have tried to make changing from waspmote api but couldnt succeed. 
How can i check the transmit status frame? cuz even if i changed the algorithms they are sended perfectly.
And i know xbee module has its own mac layer im just trying to edit it. Its not possible to implement s-mac on xbee module?
sorry for long-winded post